# How to change value in a nested object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change the value of an attribute in a dynamic nested javascript object?

Example

Object:
`"chart": {
            "height": 400,
            "width": 600,
            "margin":{"top": 0, "right": 0, "bottom": 0, "left": 0},

            "padding":{"top": 0, "right": 0, "bottom": 0, "left": 0},
            "grid" : {
                "xEnabled":"yes",
                "yEnabled":"yes",
                "color": "#ddd"
            }
        },`

How can i change the padding.top from 0 to 20 using javascript.

Any code will be helpful.

Comment: Look at this: http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/need-help-with-javascript-inheritance-and-nested-objects/

Comment: I have modified my question a bit. Also key and value to change comes from a variable. How should then we achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var whatKey = 'top';
var whatValue = 20;

var myObject = {"chart": {
            "height": 400,
            "width": 600,
            "margin":{"top": 0, "right": 0, "bottom": 0, "left": 0},

            "padding":{"top": 0, "right": 0, "bottom": 0, "left": 0},
            "grid" : {
                "xEnabled":"yes",
                "yEnabled":"yes",
                "color": "#ddd"
            }
    }
};
myObject.chart.padding[whatKey] = whatValue;
alert(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/qc18kfmj/

Comment: I have modified my question a bit. Also key and value to change comes from a variable. How should then we achieve it?

Comment: To specify the property name with a variable, use the subscript syntax. (obj[propertyname]).

Comment: I updated the answer according to your new question.

Comment: The variable containing the key may also have "padding.top". How to know whether the key to be changed is a nested or parent only

Comment: I guess that you could use myProperty.indexOf("."). But to be honest with you, I think think that you should find a JavaScript Basics tutorial and work through that one instead of asking around for every problem you face. You will benefit much more from that in the long run.
If my answer was helpful to you, please mark it as the correct answer. Good luck with your program!

Comment: The problem is sometimes the whatKey may have "padding.top" and some times "width". That is my problem i am not able to write an alogrithm to identify the depth in which the value needs to be changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60114/discussion-between-ronak-bhandari-and-folkol).

Answer (score 0):

You can change it as follows:

```
var c = {
        "chart": {
            "height": 400,
            "width": 600,
            "margin": { "top": 0, "right": 0, "bottom": 0, "left": 0 },

            "padding": { "top": 0, "right": 0, "bottom": 0, "left": 0 },
            "grid": {
                "xEnabled": "yes",
                "yEnabled": "yes",
                "color": "#ddd"
            }
        }
    };
    c['chart']['padding']['top'] = 20;

    alert(c['chart']['padding']['top']);
```